# C++; find all smaller numbers that are only divisible by 2 or 3, and no other prime number

Tags: c++

my problem is to find all natural numbers smaller or equal to n (n < 10^4), which are:

1. divisible by 2 or 3
2. indivisible by any other prime number.

The first part is of course easy, however I cannot combine it with the second one. It seems very simple, yet I cannot think of an elegant solution.

Thanks

Comment: can [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2672258/numbers-up-to-1000-divisible-by-2-or-3-and-no-other-prime) help you?

Comment: Think about the prime factorization of these kind of numbers: `2^n * 3^m` with `m` and `n` being natural numbers with `n + m > = 1`. Assuming you go through all numbers > 1 and check every single one of them for this condition, you can simply divide the number by 2 until it's no longer divisible by 2 and divide the result by 3 until it's no longer divisible by 3; if the number remaining is 1, the original number adheres to the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every natural number can be written as a mutiple of primes. It follows that all numbers satisfying your requirements can be written in the form 2<sup>a</sup>3<sup>b</sup>.

So you just need a couple of nested loops for a and b (or perhaps more eficiantly for 2<sup>a</sup> and 3<sup>b</sup>),